# Plot a point with two colors

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

I have a list of points that I plot with `ListPlot`.

I want all the points to have two different colors like in the picture

[image]

how can I do this with `Mathematica`?

Comment: Take a look at `Disk`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data = Transpose@Range[{5, 5}];
```

You can create custom `PlotMarkers` with the desired shape:

```
marker = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}], Blue, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2}]}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {marker, .1}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `PieChart` to create the desired markers:

```
pie = PieChart[{1, 1}, SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2}, 0}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {pie, .1}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Yet another alternative is to post-process the output of `ListLinePlot` with `Automatic` markers to replace the markers with `pie`:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], PlotStyle -> Dashed];
llp /. Inset[x_, p_] :> Inset[pie, p, Automatic, .3]
```

[image]

You can also use `pie` as the setting for `ChartElements` in `BubbleChart` after adding a third column to `data`:

```
BubbleChart[{##, 1} & @@@ data, ChartElements -> pie,
 Prolog -> ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Dashed][[1]]]
```

[image]