# How to plot a point with two colors?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

How can I use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191340/plot-a-point-with-two-colors) type of marker for this?

[image]

```
Plot[{x + 3, x^2 + 1}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01],
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{2, 5}]}]
```

I would be nice if the colors are added automatically from the two curves.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
f1[x_] := x + 3
f2[x_] := 1 + x^2

meshStyle = (# /. Point[x_] :> 
   Map[Inset[PieChart[{1, 1}, SectorOrigin -> Bottom], 
      #, Center,  Scaled[.1]] &, x] &);

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 MeshFunctions -> {f1[#] - f2[#] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> meshStyle]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

- We can define `PlotMarkers` by any `Graphics` object and using `ListPlot` to add such markers of points.
- We using `MeshFunctions` to get the intersection points of two curves.
- The `AspectRatio` can be any ratio,here we set `AspectRatio -> 1/2`.

```
Clear[f, g, hemipoint, plot, indexes, meshs];
hemipoint = 
  Graphics[{{ColorData[97][1], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, 2 π - π/2}]}, {ColorData[97][
      2], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}]}}, ImageSize -> 20];
f[x_] = x + 3;
g[x_] = x^2 + 1;
plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {f[#] - g[#] &}, MeshStyle -> None];
pts = Cases[plot, 
    GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> pts, ∞][[1]];
indexes = Cases[plot, Point[index_] :> index, ∞];
meshs = pts[[#]] & /@ indexes;
Show[plot, ListPlot[{meshs[[1, 2]]}, PlotMarkers -> hemipoint], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

- Define two types of `PlotMarkers`.

```
Clear[hemipoint1,hemipoint2,plot,indexes,meshs];
hemipoint1 = 
  Graphics[{{ColorData[97][1], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, 2 π - π/2}]}, {ColorData[97][
      2], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}]}}, ImageSize -> 20];
hemipoint2 = 
  Graphics[{{ColorData[97][2], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, 2 π - π/2}]}, {ColorData[97][
      1], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}]}}, ImageSize -> 20];
f[x_] = x + 3;
g[x_] = x^2 + 1;
plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {f[#] - g[#] &}, MeshStyle -> None];
pts = Cases[plot, 
    GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> pts, ∞][[1]];
indexes = Cases[plot, Point[index_] :> index, ∞];
meshs = pts[[#]] & /@ indexes;
Show[plot, 
 ListPlot[{{meshs[[1, 2]]}, {meshs[[1, 1]]}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {hemipoint1, hemipoint2}], AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's not so easy to do this automatically, and you have to account for the aspect ratio of your plot, without which you end up with a squashed marker. Here's my attempt for manual points and colour selection:

```
marker[pos_, radius_, col1_, col2_] :=
 With[{d = Disk[pos, radius, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]},
  {EdgeForm[Black], col1, d, col2, Rotate[d, Pi, pos]}]

xrange = {-5, 5};
yrange = {-5, 30};
aspect = Subtract @@ yrange/Subtract @@ xrange;
markerRadius = 0.3;
Plot[{x + 3, x^2 + 1}, {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {xrange, yrange}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 Epilog -> { 
   marker[{2, 5}, markerRadius*{1, aspect}, 
    RGBColor[0.368417`, 0.506779`, 0.709798`], 
    RGBColor[0.880722`, 0.611041`, 0.142051`]]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: plot marker]

Comment: Thanks, it is much more complex than I though even without automatically adding colors. It works great but does not work when I use it like this `Show[plot1, plot_with_marker]`. How can I fix this?

Comment: And how to make the marker circle even with any AspectRatio?